# Threading in TFTP client

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am writing a TFTP client library using C#.

```
  public class TFTPcl
 {

   public enum Opcodes
        {
            Unknown = 0,
            Read = 1,
            Write = 2,
            Data = 3,
            Ack = 4,
            Error = 5
        }

      public TFTPcl(string server)
            : this(server, 69)
        {
        }

//Get function copies the file from TFTP server to localsystem path

   public void Get(string remoteFile, string localFile)
   {

           Thread t = new Thread(() => Get(remoteFile, localFile, Modes.Octet));
            t.Start();         
    }

    public void Get(string remoteFile, string localFile, Modes tftpMode)

    {

     byte[] sendBuffer = CreateReqPacket(Opcodes.Read, remoteFile, tftpMode);

         /*process for getting the remote file from remote-server........*/ 

      }

    private byte[] CreateReqPacket(Opcodes opCode, string remoteFile, Modes tftpMode)

    {
    //Creates the TFTP request packet

    }
}

 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            TFTPcl tf = new TFTPcl("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");//Server IP
            tf.Get("del.txt","d:\\Do.txt");
            tf.Get("del.txt", "d:\\Do2.txt");

        }
    }
```

This TFTP client will made as a library, so that other application will be calling the `Get` API. Currently, I have made it as exe for testing purpose.

My question is: Does the `Get` method create the thread, when it is called simultaneously called from two different/same application? Will it cause any issues like synchronization problem?

Will it have any problem in `CreateReqPacket` function, since it is called inside the thread function (`Get` function)?

If problem persists, how to handle this situation?

Comment: Synchronization problems between threads, happen when more than one thread access a shared resource (variable, list, queue etc.) and one of them is changing the shared resource. In the little code you supplied I see no shared resource that is being written to. Of course you haven't given your implementation of the Get function and the CreateReqPacket function so I can't tell for sure.